# How to install yum on Fedora Core 6

Tags: yum

I have searched in google but have found no result and have been unable to install it yet.

I want to install yum on fedora core 6 on my server to install ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php.

How can i install it without error ?

I have ssh connection so i have to use the command prompt

Comment: yum should be there from the standard installation. If it is not, have you tried installing it from the RPM? What kind of error are you speaking about?

Comment: I assume that you are aware of how old and unsupported FC6 is?

Comment: chances are you are on a managed vps that doesn't have yum in fedora.. I know godaddy does this

Answer (score 1):

You do not absoluetly need yum to get or install packages.

You might be able to find needed packages (even yum if you wish) from the archived mirror servers.  You can find these under http://fedoraproject.org.

Have you thought of installing the latest Fedora release?

Comment: Yes I want to install latest fedora.

I know latest fedora core 12

I have now is fedora core 6.

Can I upgrade directly from 6 to 12?

Comment: Sadly, I don't think that is supported.  What you can do is copy off any important files and then do a full install of Fedora 12.

Answer (score 0):

You say "without errors" so i take it you have tried a few things already, what have you tried? and where did it go wrong?

Have you tried this guide ?
http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-fc6.html#yum

Seems to be what you're looking for, but it's quite old though (Published: 11 October 2006 (updated: 31 May 2007))

Comment: yes I tried this http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-install-yum-problems-installing-on-linux-redhat-fedora-commands-t471.html

I could not install yum

Comment: I used your link http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-fc6.html#yum
sudo: yum: command not found
message comes