# how to install yum on fedora core 6 with rpm

Tags: yum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install yum on Fedora Core 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/121077/how-to-install-yum-on-fedora-core-6)

I used this file http://www.icewalkers.com/rpm/yum/fedora-core-6/download/yum-3603.html

all the links say file not found.

I can install yum with  rpm -ivh *.rpm

I need to have yum in rpm

If you know please tell me installing yum and dependencies with rpm.

Comment: The preferred method would by to upgrade to a newer version of Fedora Core. Version 6 hasn't been supported in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Official download archive:

http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/6/i386/os/Fedora/RPMS/

Here you can find yum and all it needs.

P.S. you probably will have to modify the urls in config file to make it work

Comment: Hi moo,

When I tried to install yum 3.0-6 on fedora core 6
The following error occurs,

[root@02e7709 ~]# rpm -ivh yum-3.0-6.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
python-elementtree is needed by yum-3.0-6.noarch
python-sqlite is needed by yum-3.0-6.noarch
rpm-python is needed by yum-3.0-6.noarch
yum-metadata-parser is needed by yum-3.0-6.noarch

this is *86

Comment: This is for 64 bit http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/6/x86_64/os/Fedora/RPMS/

need to install ffmpeg

Comment: then download them too and add to install command