# install yum on fedora core 6

Tags: yum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install yum on Fedora Core 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/121077/how-to-install-yum-on-fedora-core-6)

hi,

I have installed yum through 
rpm -ivh yum-3.0-6.noarch.rpm.

The result came as

[root@02e7709 ~]# rpm -ivh yum-3.0-6.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
package yum-3.0-6 is already installed

I used this To query a RPM package, using the command:

[root@02e7709 ~]# rpm -q yum-3.0-6.noarch.rpm

Reply as follows:

[root@02e7709 ~]# rpm -q yum-3.0-6.noarch.rpm
package yum-3.0-6.noarch.rpm is not installed

both give different reply.
But yum not installed I think.

Whats the problem here
package yum-3.0-6.noarch.rpm is not installed

I used

yum install subversion

This follows

[root@02e7709 ~]# yum install subversion

Loading "installonlyn" plugin

Setting up Install Process

Setting up repositories
core                      100% |=========================| 1.1 kB    00:00

rpmforge                  100% |=========================| 1.1 kB    00:00

Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: updates

What is the error baseurl for repo?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why on earth are you still using FC6? Fedora 13 will be out in a month or two...

Comment: I am using netsol fedora core 6. it comes by default. can I update 6 to 12?

Will it solve problems?

Site is running on the server. If file does not affect i will upgrade to 12

Any suggessions please reply me

Answer (score 1):

The repositories for Fedora Core 6 aren't there anymore.

FC 6 support ended when FC 8 came out. 
If you want to run a supported OS, you are going to have to upgrade. I am sure this will be very complicated going from Fedora Core 6 up to Fedora 12 and will probably mean a reinstall.

Certainly if this is a production server I would question how security patches are being applied. I think the answer will probably be they aren't.

Edit:
To answer you question:
baseurl for repo is the "base URL for the repository". In other words the location of the updates available. As FC 6 is not supported the repository is no longer available.

Alternatively you could [install subversion from source](http://subversion.apache.org/source-code.html).